# Accidentally generated new openssl key after receiving certificates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, openssl, digital-ocean, namecheap

I was trying to figure out what I did wrong when uploading a new custom certificate to my rails application, and for whatever reason I thought it would be a good idea to rerun this command into my digitalocean @deploy user, even though I had already done this command and did all the steps for generating an ssl key with namecheap.com, and got PositiveSSL Certificate. Now, the private key does not match up with my positivessl certificate, and I cannot find the old privatekey anywhere. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I should do about this?

```
  openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout myapp.net.key -out myapp.net.csr
```

Answer (score 0):

If you lost your private key, you need to reissue the SSL Certificate.
The process is free in most Comodo (Sectigo) resellers like namecheap.
Just follow instructions on https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/811/70/how-do-i-reissue-my-ssl-certificate